# Migrating from Microsoft VB6 and SQLite to Linux

Tags: application-development

I am doing business programming and wish to migrate to Umbuntu.
What would be a similar development environment in Umbuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Gambas is a free alternative to VB6 on Linux.
However, it use a slightly different syntax.